# How to read from the buffer last valuse at spisific time, using fieldtrip toolbox

Tags: matlab

I want  to read from fieldtrip toolbox buffer in specific time, I perform an experiment that causes brain stimulation, so i want to read the eeg data reaction of the 
experiment.

I was able to read continuous data, here is my code:

```
run=1;
filename = 'buffer://localhost:1972';       %set buffer
% read the header for the first time to determine number of channels and sampling rate
hdr = ft_read_header(filename, 'cache', true);  %header of buffer
count      = 0;
prevSample = 0;
blocksize  = hdr.Fs;        %size if readig on blick
chanindx   = 1:hdr.nChans;
while true
  hdr = ft_read_header(filename, 'cache', true);
  newsamples = (hdr.nSamples*hdr.nTrials-prevSample);
  if newsamples>=blocksize
    begsample  = prevSample+1;
    endsample  = prevSample+blocksize ;
    prevSample  = endsample;
    count       = count + 1;
    dat = ft_read_data(filename, 'header', hdr, 'begsample', begsample, 'endsample', endsample, 'chanindx', chanindx);
    time = (begsample:endsample)/hdr.Fs;
    vals= (dat([15 1 2 3],1:end)).';%get rows 1,2,3 and 15=timestamp, transpose it
    plot(time,vals);
    run=run+1;
    if(run==100)
        break;
    end
  end % if new samples available
end % while true
```

Comment: Are you having an error from this? Please edit your question to include more information on the problems you are encountering

Comment: I dont have an error, this is the code of reading continuous data, i want to know if there is a way to read data from the buffer when i want, not read all the data.